# android highlight cardview border

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-shape

I'm using cards in a recycleview and would like to highlight some of them.

the first thought i have is a different shadow or border with a bright color, but so far i was not able to find any properties that would adjust it

this is my card view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/giveawayCardHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/raffleThumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 />

            <com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.ui.FontFitTextView
                android:id="@+id/raffleOwner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:text="viajandocomgabi"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalFont" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/raffleDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="@string/raf_date_label"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalFont" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/giveawayButtonsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/startButton"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/cardButtonSize"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cardButtonSize"


                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_play" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/cardButtonSize"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cardButtonSize"

                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_trash" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/ticketAmountLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_tickets"
                android:text="@string/you_have"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normalFont" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is how i would like to be:

[image]

the best scenario is switch the default shadow color for something brighter, but if that is impossible an inner border would be ok

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda ugly but you could add another field on your model that that you will use as basis for setting a different background on the cardview. Then on the adapter, change the background of the cardview programmatically depending on it's status. You need to notifyDatasetChanged often though if needed.

Answer (score 0):

for inner border you can create a `xml` `drawable` file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="8dp" />
</shape>
```

then put it as `background` of the `CardView`s first child.

set `cardCorner radius` and `xml` `background` `corner radius` the same as each other.